# How to get last two observations from a dataset in SAS without using sort or First. and Last. or Do loop

Tags: if-statement, sas, dataset

Below code will solve for getting last 2 observations from the dataset without using loops, first & last dot concept or sorting.

```
data a;
set sashelp.cars nobs=_nobs_;/*create the temporary variable to store total no of obs*/
if _N_ ge _nobs_-1;/*Now compare the automatic variable _N_ to _nobs_*/
run;
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is a question here.

You can also use the `POINT=` option on the `SET` statement. You have to explicitly end the data step since most data steps end when they read past the end of the input data and this step cannot do that.

```
data want;
  do p=max(1,nobs-1) to nobs;
    set have point=p nobs=nobs;
    output;
  end;
  stop;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

A DATA step is an implicit loop with an automatic index variable `_N_`.  You can leverage that fact to implicitly output rows without an explicit `DO` loop.  As per @Tom, the `point=` option is used so the entire data set does not need to be read to reach the last two rows.

Example:

```
data want;
  if _N_ > min(2,_Z_) then stop;

  _P_ = _Z_ - min(2,_Z_) + _N_; 

  set sashelp.class point=_P_ nobs=_Z_;
run;
```